# Microsoft Defender vs AVG 9.0

Tags: windows, avg-antivirus, windows-defender

From various forums it appears that AVG 9.0 disables Microsoft Defender.  Is there any way to stop that behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - don't use AVG.

In recent editions it has gone downhill fast.

Seriously though, it is because AVG pro comes with Anti Malware, and they do not want you using Defender. I don't think it gets disabled with the free edition, but if it does, you may want to look else where.

Quite frankly, if you like Windows Defender, you may want to take a look at [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/), In my books it is now by far the best free AV (and better than a bunch of the pay ones) out there. Low foot print, and fast speeds.

Comment: It gets disabled in the free edition starting with AVG 9.0

Comment: +1 for the mention of Security Essentials.  Go get that instead of Defender and AVG.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to turn back on Windows definder. But I turn off real-time protection in WIndows definder. Thjis allows AVG to be my main antivrus & spyware program. I set windows definder to scan once a week, just incase anything slips by AVG that Windows definder will pick up in their scan

Answer (score 0):

AVG has really been dropping the ball lately. They keep adding unnecessary bulk and don't have that great of a detection record either. I used to install AVG Free on all PCs that I worked on and cleaned/formatted for people. This is no longer the case.

Regarding your question. AVG knows about this issue and has been contacted by many dissatisfied users. Their official response is that Microsoft told them to disable Microsoft Defender. Apparently only one software package is supposed to utilize real time scanning. Therefore AVG decided to forcefully disable Defender when it is installed. It also seems to disable other things that it has no business disabling. I wouldn't be so angry about this situation if they gave users an option to choose what is disabled or not, but they don't. They are sticking with their decision and I doubt you will be able to do anything about this.

My suggestion? Get a different free antivirus. There are other options that not only allow you more control and don't disable Microsoft Defender, but they also have higher detection rates.

Give these two a try:
[avast! Home Edition](http://www.avast.com/eng/avast_4_home.html)
[Avira AntiVir Personal](http://www.free-av.com/en/download/1/download_avira_antivir_personal__free_antivirus.html)

If you decide that you absolutely need to stay with AVG for whatever reason you will be stuck with Windows Defender disabled. Considering the update deadline from versions of AVG below 9.0 is December 1st, you don't even have the option of using a version that isn't so intrusive on your system.